# Kotlin not picking up resource ids

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to develop an app using Kotlin. I read about the possibility of not using findViewById again by just referencing the ids directly using Kotlin extensions. I have applied the plugin properly with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

On my build.gradle

However, when I try to reference with:

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_event.view.event_cover
```

Android Studio recognizes only until the view part, that is

```
kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_event.view
```

meaning that I can work my way to this point using Ctrl + Space. But after "view" I get no suggestion and if I put the id then it says unrecognized reference.

What am I doing wrong?

To add to this, this used to work until I refactored my class and moved it to another package.

Comment: The same happenned to me. Try building your project again. Also which Android Studio version are you using? Cause it is fixed in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5

Comment: Well im using Canary 4.... Ill update then.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Not sure if that's actually any different, but are you able to access the views if you import all of them via `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_event.view.*`?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5. If your using older version then building your project again should help.

Comment: Try updating the Kotlin compiler. I am using `1.1.3`